# How to grant access to a git repository hosted in an amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

I have a repository hosted in an instance on amazon EC2 server, and I want to grant access to that repository to a client **without supplying the instance identity file (.pem)**. What's the most secure solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can install something like [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) then you can specify SSH keys for each user.